# Can't access parsed JSON object's properties

Tags: javascript, json, api, puppeteer

I'm trying to learn some javascript by creating a web scraper for majestic.com using puppeteer, I have successfully filled the form for the POST request, submitted it and got to a page with JSON (here is a copy of the page content https://jsfiddle.net/nxmavy0k/) that I needed and tried to save it like so:

```
myObj = await page.evaluate(() =>  {
       return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body > pre").innerText);
   });

   console.log("innerText now contains the JSON");
   console.log(myObj);
```

This works great and logs what I think is the correct object. The problem is that I can't access the properties with something like

```
console.log(myObj.Code); // should log "OK"
```

or

```
console.log(myObj.DataTables);
```

The error says Unexpected end of JSON input. Please, where is the mistake here?

Comment: does this mean your promise is erroring out?

Comment: means `document.querySelector("body > pre").innerText` isn't valid JSON

Comment: please provide the outcome of `document.querySelector("body > pre").innerText` to us, as it probably is not valid JSON

Comment: I thought the same @Flo ... but `console.log(myObj);` apparently works!!!! not sure how that could work, then the very next line says `Unexpected end of JSON input` when trying to `console.log(myObj.Code)` I suspect the actual code the OP is using is far removed from what he's showing

Comment: I just tried to run the scrit and 3 out of 4 times it gave an error 2 out of 4 times, sometimes it loads the object fully, but more often it is like this
https://jsfiddle.net/k6odx7ve/

Comment: Not enough time to load the object?

Comment: here's the full code
https://jsfiddle.net/uhyL18m0/

Comment: @Ctznkane525 yes, most probably promise/timing problem

Comment: The error you report - `Unexpected end of JSON input` - is only ever triggered by JSON.parse, and it always means the JSON was invalid.